# how to find specific key in object using chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

This might be a huge newbie question but I've got no clue.

I'm using chrome inspect with debugger to check my JS. Right now i'm using gmaps with marker objects. When i open an object in the chrome console, to show the object keys, there is long list with many different subkeys.

The problem is that there are so many subkeys its's nearly impossible to find my specific key.

How do i easily search through all the key for a specific (custom) key? Is there some kind of search function I can use to find a specific key and its path, so that i can call it in my JS?

Comment: There should be a menu option if you right-click the object, that says 'Use in commandline' or similar.

Comment: You could try running `JSON.stringify(foo)` in the console. That will give your object as a string. You can copy the string into your editor (or an online JSON formatter like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) and then CTRL+F for your custom key.

Comment: if i use JSON.stringify i get 'Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON'

Comment: A simple `foo["SomeKey"]` or maybe `console.dir(foo["SomeKey"])` in the console should do it?

Comment: the problem isn't that i can't access attributes. The problem is I can't find the key. there are 15 keys with each 15 subkeys witch each 15 subkeys etc etc. and somewhere my custom key is hiding (but i'm not even sure of that). I can't go through all the keys by hand because that will take way too long.

Answer (score 0):

You can try dumping the object using the simple code below. Then on your chrome browser hit "<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>" to bring up the console and right click on the "LOG" section and save the log file to a text editor and slowly review from there.

```
for (var key in gmapObject) {
    console.log('The key is ' + key + ' and the value is =' + value + '.');
}
```

Actually you shouldn't have to dump the object to find stuff.

You may want to look at the google map api page.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference

For instance, if you are looking for something in the markers then you should use the API provided by the marker gmap object to dump the value using the actual API. For instance if you want to know the coordinates of your marker it will be something like

marker.getPosition().toString()

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Marker

Comment: I don't really know what part of the the api docs to use since it's not a preset key. I added a custom key called category to the markers (and i'm not even sure it worked). I can't find the category key on the marker object (but it COULD be hiding amonst a million other keys, so i'm just trying to find out if there is an easy way to find my key)

Comment: How are you setting the Category? Are you using the set API of Marker? Note Marker extends the google.maps.MVCObject which provides a pair of set and get API. I believe if you use the set() method you should be able to use get() to retrieve.